# How to create expandable confirmation design in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am a beginner in Ionic and trying to design a layout for Cricket Scoring app.

When use clicks on the buttons a popup should appear for confirmation.

At first I thought I can use it with ion-pull-up footer but it does not work properly.

Can some one please advise me how to achieve similar layout ?

I have attached screenshots here.

Thank you

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use AlertController component.

See https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/

Comment: AlertController will open a new modal but instead I want to just expand the div just like the screenshot.

Comment: Ok I understand. So you can do this with a *ngIf directive like the official most common usage : https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#most-common-usage

Answer (score 0):

**The best way you can use Ionic Accordion**

Reference Links

[Link1](https://ionicacademy.com/accordion-list-ionic/)
[Link2](https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-an-accordion-list-in-ionic/)

Comment: I tried using accordion, the only problem is accordion pushes other content either up or down. I could not find out how to fix it's position and overlay it on top of other content.